# Xml to Json with Multiple LineItems

Tags: arrays, xslt, multidimensional-array, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

Am trying to convert xml to json but the multipel lineitems are not formed during xml to json converiosn. we always have single or multiple Lineitems in a xml message with same name as 'vpoItemList' , 'vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList' and 'vpoShipDtlCsGroupList'.

Request to check the code to get all the lineitems in the json file as expected json file. Getting error message as Error: xml-to-json: duplicate key value {vpoItemList}.

Input xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ns0:PO_Message
    xmlns:ns0="http://test.com/Test">
    <domainId>MAIL</domainId>
    <hubDomainId>MAIL</hubDomainId>
    <isForReference>false</isForReference>
    <status>releasedToVendor</status>
    <docStatus>active</docStatus>
    <editingStatus>confirmed</editingStatus>
    <vpoNo>28288</vpoNo>
    <vpoDate>2021-02-23</vpoDate>
    <instructions>METAL-No Size:1360600001-Article Number</instructions>
    <businessRefNo>28118</businessRefNo>
    <totalItems>1</totalItems>
    <totalQty>160</totalQty>
    <season>
        <code>F21</code>
    </season>
    <custId>
        <refNo>C000001</refNo>
    </custId>
    <vendorId>
        <vendorCode>41843</vendorCode>
    </vendorId>
    <headerFactory>
        <refNo>F000026</refNo>
        <factCode>900088</factCode>
    </headerFactory>
    <vpoItemList>
        <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
        <itemName>Base Camp 6 Footprint</itemName>
        <customerItemNo>19979</customerItemNo>
        <lotNo>1</lotNo>
        <itemDesc>Base Camp 6 Footprint</itemDesc>
        <shipQty>160</shipQty>
        <planedQty>160</planedQty>
        <qtyPerExportCarton>160</qtyPerExportCarton>
        <qtyPerInnerCarton>160</qtyPerInnerCarton>
        <factCode>900088</factCode>
        <refNo>19979-2021-0002-41843-1</refNo>
        <uom>
            <code>PCS</code>
        </uom>
        <brand>
            <code>MAIL Co-op</code>
        </brand>
        <itemId>
            <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
        </itemId>
        <portOfLoading>
            <code>DLC Dalian</code>
        </portOfLoading>
        <vpoItemCsList>
            <itemLotNo>19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1</itemLotNo>
            <vpoItemColorRef>METAL</vpoItemColorRef>
            <vpoItemColorId>
                <refNo>METAL</refNo>
                <shortName>METAL</shortName>
            </vpoItemColorId>
            <vpoItemSizeId>
                <refNo>No Size</refNo>
                <displayName>No Size</displayName>
            </vpoItemSizeId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
            </itemId>
            <lotNo>1</lotNo>
        </vpoItemCsList>
        <factId>
            <factCode>900088</factCode>
        </factId>
    </vpoItemList>
    <vpoItemList>
        <itemNo>22825-2021-0001-43095</itemNo>
        <itemName>Flash 22 Member Exclusive</itemName>
        <customerItemNo>22825</customerItemNo>
        <lotNo>1</lotNo>
        <itemDesc>Flash 22 Member Exclusive</itemDesc>
        <shipQty>160</shipQty>
        <planedQty>160</planedQty>
        <qtyPerExportCarton>160</qtyPerExportCarton>
        <qtyPerInnerCarton>160</qtyPerInnerCarton>
        <factCode>900088</factCode>
        <refNo>22825-2021-0001-43095-1</refNo>
        <uom>
            <code>PCS</code>
        </uom>
        <brand>
            <code>MAIL Co-op</code>
        </brand>
        <itemId>
            <itemNo>22825-2021-0001-43095</itemNo>
        </itemId>
        <portOfLoading>
            <code>DLC Dalian</code>
        </portOfLoading>
        <vpoItemCsList>
            <itemLotNo>22825-2021-0001-43095-Lot1</itemLotNo>
            <vpoItemColorRef>UNDYED</vpoItemColorRef>
            <vpoItemColorId>
                <refNo>UNDYED</refNo>
                <shortName>UNDYED</shortName>
            </vpoItemColorId>
            <vpoItemSizeRef>One Size</vpoItemSizeRef>
            <vpoItemSizeId>
                <refNo>One Size</refNo>
                <displayName>One Size</displayName>
                <sizeUniqueKey>SIZE1</sizeUniqueKey>
            </vpoItemSizeId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>22825-2021-0001-43095</itemNo>
            </itemId>
            <lotNo>1</lotNo>
        </vpoItemCsList>
        <factId>
            <factCode>900088</factCode>
        </factId>
    </vpoItemList>
    <vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>
        <qty>160</qty>
        <refNo>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1</refNo>
        <vpoItemRef>19979-2021-0002-41843-1</vpoItemRef>
        <vpoItemId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
            </itemId>
        </vpoItemId>
        <vpoShipRef>00001</vpoShipRef>
        <vpoShipId>
            <shipmentNo>00001</shipmentNo>
            <originalShipmentDate>2021-08-17</originalShipmentDate>
            <shipmentDate>2021-08-23</shipmentDate>
            <originalInDcDate>2021-09-15</originalInDcDate>
            <inDcDate>2021-09-15</inDcDate>
            <refNo>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1</refNo>
            <shipMode>
                <code>3</code>
            </shipMode>
            <finalDestination>
                <code>0001</code>
            </finalDestination>
            <portOfLoading>
                <code>DLC Dalian</code>
            </portOfLoading>
        </vpoShipId>
        <shipMode>
            <code>3</code>
        </shipMode>
        <portOfLoading>
            <code>DLC Dalian</code>
        </portOfLoading>
    </vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>
    <vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>
        <qty>630</qty>
        <refNo>00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1</refNo>
        <vpoItemRef>22825-2021-0001-43095-1</vpoItemRef>
        <vpoItemId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>22825-2021-0001-43095</itemNo>
            </itemId>
        </vpoItemId>
        <vpoShipRef>00001</vpoShipRef>
        <vpoShipId>
            <shipmentNo>00001</shipmentNo>
            <originalShipmentDate>2021-08-17</originalShipmentDate>
            <shipmentDate>2021-08-23</shipmentDate>
            <originalInDcDate>2021-09-15</originalInDcDate>
            <inDcDate>2021-09-15</inDcDate>
            <refNo>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1</refNo>
            <shipMode>
                <code>3</code>
            </shipMode>
            <finalDestination>
                <code>0001</code>
            </finalDestination>
            <portOfLoading>
                <code>DLC Dalian</code>
            </portOfLoading>
        </vpoShipId>
        <shipMode>
            <code>3</code>
        </shipMode>
        <portOfLoading>
            <code>DLC Dalian</code>
        </portOfLoading>
    </vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>
    <vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
        <itemLotNo>19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1</itemLotNo>
        <shipmentNo>00001</shipmentNo>
        <colorSizeQty>160</colorSizeQty>
        <refNo>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1/METAL/No Size</refNo>
        <vpoItemRef>19979-2021-0002-41843-1</vpoItemRef>
        <vpoItemId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
            </itemId>
        </vpoItemId>
        <vpoShipRef>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1</vpoShipRef>
        <vpoItemColorRef>METAL</vpoItemColorRef>
        <vpoItemSizeRef>No Size</vpoItemSizeRef>
        <vpoShipDtlColorRef>1</vpoShipDtlColorRef>
        <vpoShipDtlSizeRef>1</vpoShipDtlSizeRef>
    </vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
    <vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
        <itemLotNo>22825-2021-0001-43095-Lot1</itemLotNo>
        <shipmentNo>00001</shipmentNo>
        <colorSizeQty>630</colorSizeQty>
        <refNo>00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1/UNDYED/One Size</refNo>
        <vpoItemRef>22825-2021-0001-43095-1</vpoItemRef>
        <itemSizeId>035ae556951b413588cb935fe8abe89e</itemSizeId>
        <itemColorId>92bdbbe775cd470dbfaba3b58597f0a8</itemColorId>
        <itemColor />
        <vpoItemId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>22825-2021-0001-43095</itemNo>
            </itemId>
        </vpoItemId>
        <vpoShipRef>00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1</vpoShipRef>
        <vpoItemColorRef>UNDYED</vpoItemColorRef>
        <vpoItemSizeRef>One Size</vpoItemSizeRef>
        <vpoShipDtlColorRef>1</vpoShipDtlColorRef>
        <vpoShipDtlSizeRef>1</vpoShipDtlSizeRef>
    </vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
</ns0:PO_Message>
```

XSLT Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*" priority="5">
    <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
      <map>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </map>        
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[(*) and . castable as xs:double]">
    <number key="{local-name()}">{.}</number>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[* and not(*[6])]">
    <map key="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[* and *[6]]">
    <array key="{local-name()}">
        <map>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </map>
    </array>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList/vpoShipId">
      <map key="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList | vpoShipDtlCsGroupList" priority="20">
    <array key="{local-name()}">
        <array>
          <map>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </map>          
        </array>
    </array>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected json file:

```
    {
    "domainId": "MAIL",
    "hubDomainId": "MAIL",
    "isForReference": false,
    "status": "releasedToVendor",
    "docStatus": "active",
    "editingStatus": "confirmed",
    "vpoNo": "28288",
    "vpoDate": "2021-02-23",
        "instructions": "METAL-No Size:1360600001-Article Number",
    "businessRefNo": "2818",
    "totalItems": 1,
    "totalQty": 160,
    "season": {
        "code": "F21"
    },
    "custId": {
        "refNo": "C000001"
    },
    "vendorId": {
        "vendorCode": "41843"
    },
    "headerFactory": {
        "refNo": "F000026",
        "factCode": "900088"
    },
    "vpoItemList": [
        {
            "itemNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843",
            "itemName": "Base Camp 6 Footprint",
            "customerItemNo": "19979",
            "lotNo": 1,
            "itemDesc": "Base Camp 6 Footprint",
                        "shipQty": 160,
                        "planedQty": 160,
                        "qtyPerExportCarton": 160,
            "qtyPerInnerCarton": 160,
            "factCode": "900088",
            "refNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
            "uom": {
                "code": "PCS"
            },
            "brand": {
                "code": "MAIL Co-op"
            },
            "itemId": {
                "itemNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843"
            },
            "portOfLoading": {
                "code": "DLC Dalian"
            },
            "vpoItemCsList": [
                {
                    "itemLotNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1",
                    "vpoItemColorRef": "METAL",
                    "vpoItemColorId": {
                        "refNo": "METAL",
                        "shortName": "METAL"
                    },
                    "vpoItemSizeId": {
                        "refNo": "No Size",
                        "displayName": "No Size"
                    },
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843"
                    },
                    "lotNo": 1
                }
            ],
            "factId": {
                "factCode": "900088"
            }
        },
        {
            "itemNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095",
            "itemName": "Flash 22 Member Exclusive",
            "customerItemNo": "22825",
            "lotNo": 1,
            "itemDesc": "Flash 22 Member Exclusive",
                        "shipQty": 160,
                        "planedQty": 160,
                        "qtyPerExportCarton": 160,
            "qtyPerInnerCarton": 160,
            "factCode": "900088",
            "refNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095-1",
            "uom": {
                "code": "PCS"
            },
            "brand": {
                "code": "MAIL Co-op"
            },
            "itemId": {
                "itemNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095"
            },
            "portOfLoading": {
                "code": "DLC Dalian"
            },
            "vpoItemCsList": [
                                {
                    "itemLotNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095-Lot1",
                    "vpoItemColorRef": "UNDYED",
                    "vpoItemColorId": {
                        "refNo": "UNDYED",
                        "shortName": "UNDYED"
                        },
                    "vpoItemSizeRef": "One Size",
                    "vpoItemSizeId": {
                        "refNo": "One Size",
                        "displayName": "One Size",
                        "sizeUniqueKey": "SIZE1"
                        },
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095"
                        },
                    "lotNo": 1
                    
                }
            ],
            "factId": {
                "factCode": "900088"
            }
        }       
    ],
    "vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList": [
        [
            {
                "qty": 160,
                "refNo": "00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                "vpoItemRef": "19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                "vpoItemId": {
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843"
                    }
                },
                "vpoShipRef": "00001",
                "vpoShipId": {
                    "shipmentNo": "00001",
                    "originalShipmentDate": "2021-08-17",
                    "shipmentDate": "2021-08-23",
                    "originalInDcDate": "2021-09-15",
                    "inDcDate": "2021-09-15",
                    "refNo": "00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                    "shipMode": {
                        "code": "3"
                    },
                    "finalDestination": {
                            "code": "0001"
                            },
                            "portOfLoading": {
                        "code": "DLC Dalian"
                    }
                },
                "shipMode": {
                    "code": "3"
                            },
                            "portOfLoading": {
                            "code": "DLC Dalian"
                }
            },
                  {
                "qty": 630,
                "refNo": "00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1",
                "vpoItemRef": "22825-2021-0001-43095-1",
                "vpoItemId": {
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095"
                    }
                },
                "vpoShipRef": "00001",
                "vpoShipId": {
                    "shipmentNo": "00001",
                    "originalShipmentDate": "2021-08-17",
                    "shipmentDate": "2021-08-23",
                    "originalInDcDate": "2021-09-15",
                    "inDcDate": "2021-09-15",
                    "refNo": "00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                    "shipMode": {
                        "code": "3"
                    },
                    "finalDestination": {
                            "code": "0001"
                            },
                            "portOfLoading": {
                        "code": "DLC Dalian"
                    }
                },
                "shipMode": {
                    "code": "3"
                            },
                            "portOfLoading": {
                            "code": "DLC Dalian"
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "vpoShipDtlCsGroupList": [
        [
            {
                "itemLotNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1",
                "shipmentNo": "00001",
                "colorSizeQty": 160,
                "refNo": "00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1/METAL/No Size",
                "vpoItemRef": "19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                "vpoItemId": {
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843"
                    }
                },
                "vpoShipRef": "00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                "vpoItemColorRef": "METAL",
                "vpoItemSizeRef": "No Size",
                "vpoShipDtlColorRef": "1",
                "vpoShipDtlSizeRef": "1"
            }
        ],
        [
                        {
                "itemLotNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095-Lot1",
                "shipmentNo": "00001",
                "colorSizeQty": 630,
                "refNo": "00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1/UNDYED/One Size",
                "vpoItemRef": "22825-2021-0001-43095-1",
                "itemSizeId": "035ae556951b413588cb935fe8abe89e",
                "itemColorId": "92bdbbe775cd470dbfaba3b58597f0a8",
                "itemColor": {},
                "vpoItemId": {
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095"
                         }
                    
                },
                "vpoShipRef": "00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1",
                "vpoItemColorRef": "UNDYED",
                "vpoItemSizeRef": "One Size",
                "vpoShipDtlColorRef": "1",
                "vpoShipDtlSizeRef": "1"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you tag this as XSLT 2.0 although you use XSLT 3.

In general, if you have several child elements of the same name and want to "lump" them together as you need in the JSON representation as member of an array, you could consider using `xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()"` and then, if there is more than one item in the group (e.g. `<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">`) output the array you need and otherwise do your normal processing to construct a map.

I have no complete, off the shell code that handles all options, an example to use grouping to construct an array is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and . castable as xs:double]">
    <number key="{local-name()}">{.}</number>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
      <map>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
                      <array key="{local-name()}">
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                      </array>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would transform e.g.

```
<root>
    <item>
        <number>3.14</number>
        <name>foo</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <number>42</number>
        <name>bar</name>
    </item>
    <data>test</data>
</root>
```

into

```
{ "item" : 
    [ 
      { "number" : 3.14,
        "name" : "foo" },
      
      { "number" : 42,
        "name" : "bar" } ],
    "data" : "test" }
```

You will need to improve/extend/adapt that probably to your needs.

Comment: Am trying to add the template at the end of the xsl code but the error is same.<xsl:template match="vpoItemList">
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="@vpoItemList">
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

Comment: <xsl:template match="vpoItemList">
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="@vpoItemList">
 <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: Please share the correct template to get the values when the line items are 1 or more than 1

Comment: @raviteja, I have a snippet, but do understand that due to the various ways the input and the wanted output can be structured it is hard to write short/compact do it all code so be prepared to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: - Am trying to use the same code but the child elements 'EmployeeCode' is not recognizing. Error:Error executing XSLT at line 15 : xml-to-json: Child elements of <map> must have a key attribute <root><Name>Alex</Name><Age>42</Age><item><number>3.14</number><name>foo</name><EmployeeCode><id>F21</id></EmployeeCode></item><item><number>42</number><name>bar</name></item><data>test</data></root>

Comment: <root>
 <Name>Alex</Name>
 <Age>42</Age>
 <item>
  <number>3.14</number>
  <name>foo</name>
  <EmployeeCode>
   <id>F21</id>
   <Department>
    <Designation>Engineer</Designation>
   </Department>
  </EmployeeCode>
 </item>
 <item>
  <number>42</number>
  <name>bar</name>
 </item>
 <data>test</data>
</root>

Comment: Please share the template to consider the multiple child elements  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <title>
            <xsl:value-of select="$map/item[@key = current()]"/>
        </title>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>